# How can I pass a C++ lambda to a C-callback that expects a function pointer and a context?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to register a callback in a C-API that uses the standard function-pointer+context paradigm. Here's what the api looks like:

```
void register_callback(void(*callback)(void *), void * context);
```

What I'd really like to do is be able to register a C++ lambda as the callback. Additionally, I want the lambda to be one that has captured variables (ie. can't be converted to a straight stateless `std::function`)

What kind of adapter code would I need to write to be able to register a lambda as the callback?

Comment: while std::function<T> is a type erasure mechanism capable of holding a lambda expression, it's not a lambda

Comment: That's fair. Did the dicrepancy prevent you from understanding the question? Is there there a way I can rewrite it?

Comment: it could be, I haven't given the question a further thought to be entirely honest with you, but you could rewrite saying you need to pull the function pointer out of std::function<> rather than out of a lambda

Comment: That sounds great. Is there a way to pull a context out of it? Some sort of state that I could pass as the context pointer to the C-api?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simple approach is to stick the lambda into a `std::function<void()>` which is kept somewhere. Potentially it is allocated on the heap and merely referenced by the `void*` registered with the entity taking the callback. The callback would then simply be a function like this:

```
extern "C" void invoke_function(void* ptr) {
    (*static_cast<std::function<void()>*>(ptr))();
}
```

Note that `std::function<S>` can hold function objects with state, e.g., lambda functions with a non-empty capture. You could register a callback like this:

```
register_callback(&invoke_function,
  new std::function<void()>([=](){ ... }));
```

Answer (score 21):

The most efficient way is to `voidify` the lambda directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

template<class...Args>
struct callback {
  void(*function)(void*, Args...)=nullptr;
  std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> state;
};
template<typename... Args, typename Lambda>
callback<Args...> voidify( Lambda&& l ) {
  using Func = typename std::decay<Lambda>::type;
  std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> data(
    new Func(std::forward<Lambda>(l)),
    +[](void* ptr){ delete (Func*)ptr; }
  );
  return {
    +[](void* v, Args... args)->void {
      Func* f = static_cast< Func* >(v);
      (*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    },
    std::move(data)
  };
}

void register_callback( void(*function)(void*), void * p ) {
  function(p); // to test
}
void test() {
  int x = 0;
  auto closure = [&]()->void { ++x; };
  auto voidified = voidify(closure);
  register_callback( voidified.function, voidified.state.get() );
  register_callback( voidified.function, voidified.state.get() );
  std::cout << x << "\n";
}
int main() {
  test();
}
```

here `voidify` takes a lambda and (optionally) a list of arguments, and generates a traditional C-style callback-`void*` pair. The `void*` is owned by a `unique_ptr` with a special deleter so its resources are properly cleaned up.

The advantage of this over a `std::function` solution is efficiency -- I eliminated one level of run-time indirection.  The lifetime that the callback is valid is also clear, in that it is in the `std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>` returned by `voidify`.

`unique_ptr<T,D>`s can be `move`d into `shared_ptr<T>` if you want a more complex lifetime.

---

The above mixes lifetime with data, and type erasure with utility.  We can split it:

```
template<class Lambda, class...Args>
struct callback {
  void(*function)(void*, Args...)=nullptr;
  Lambda state;
};

template<typename... Args, typename Lambda>
callback<typename std::decay<Lambda>::type, Args...> voidify( Lambda&& l ) {
  using Func = typename std::decay<Lambda>::type;
  return {
    +[](void* v, Args... args)->void {
      Func* f = static_cast< Func* >(v);
      (*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    },
    std::forward<Lambda>(l)
  };
}
```

Now `voidify` does not allocate.  Simply store your voidify for the lifetime of the callback, passing a pointer-to-`second` as your `void*` along side the `first` function pointer.

If you need to store this construct off the stack, converting the lambda to a `std::function` may help.  Or use the first variant above.

```
void test() {
  int x = 0;
  auto closure = [&]()->void { ++x; };
  auto voidified = voidify(closure);
  register_callback( voidified.function, &voidified.state );
  register_callback( voidified.function, &voidified.state );
  std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm impressed or horrified by the word "voidified"

Comment: Has anybody had success making `voidify` work for a callback signature that has multiple arguments? When I add arguments to the closure and arguments to the callback function signature, the type system always thinks the type of `voidified.first` is `void (*)(void*)`

Comment: @ChrisCleeland You have to pass in `<Args...>` explicitly, it cannot be deduced from the lambda.  Is that your issue?

Comment: Ahhh. So if the callback signature is `void(*)(int, long long)` then one needs to use `voidify<int, long long>(closure)` along with `auto closure = [=](int, long long) { ... }`.

Comment: @ChrisCleeland For callback `void(*)(void*, int, long long)` you call `auto cb = voidify<int, long long>([&](int x, long long l){ /* code */ });`.  For lambdas be useful as callbacks, the callback must be a `void*` userdata and a function-taking `void*` couple.  You also have to modify `voidify` if the C-style callback takes the "userdata" `void*` other than as the 1st argument.

Comment: *"The lifetime that the callback is valid is also clear,"* Well maybe the lifetime is clear, but it's different from the points in the code where using it doesn't produce UB, due to the captures of the lambda.

Comment: @dyp Sure, but at least the lambda isn't being copied around indefinitely by errant std functions.  ;)

Comment: Hm. Maybe I just don't like the example... most C callback registries I know actually store the function pointer somewhere to be called later, ignoring the current scope. Passing in a lambda with ref-capture then becomes a code smell, even if it's fine here.

Comment: @dyp In that case, that API had better have an unregister mechanism.  If it does, you have to store the `voidify` result (the `callback<?>` struct) until that unregister occurs.  It is just bog standard resource management?

Comment: My issue is with the ref-capture, not the `voidify` object. You provide an elegant mechanism to manage the required state for type erasure / providing a `void(void*)` adapter, but if someone puts int a lambda with ref-capture there's a not quite obvious lifetime issue. Essentially the thing that `std::thread` tries to prevent by copying everything.

Comment: @dyp Sure, you do have to know that `[&]` is only something you do when your lambda and its copies have limited lifetime.  This isn't unique to C style callbacks however?  If you had a std function callback, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Yes this is not unique to C-style callbacks. I've seen a minor improvement by forcing `voidify(&closure)` to show that closure it itself responsible for its lifetime (and those of its captures). We don't have a borrow checker so I don't see how it would be possible to prevent this mistake. I wanted to highlight it for someone who reads just the code, this is something that I think can easily happen, especially if you consider the lifetime issue to be solved (because it is solved for `callback<>`).

Answer (score 7):

A lambda function is compatible with C-callback function as long as it doesn't have capture variables.
Force to put something new to old one with new way doesn't make sense.
How about following old-fashioned way?

```
typedef struct
{
  int cap_num;
} Context_t;

int cap_num = 7;

Context_t* param = new Context_t;
param->cap_num = cap_num;   // pass capture variable
register_callback([](void* context) -> void {
    Context_t* param = (Context_t*)context;
    std::cout << "cap_num=" << param->cap_num << std::endl;
}, param);
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to get use a lamda function as a C funtion pointer is this:

```
auto fun=+[](){ //add code here }
```

see this answer for a example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56145419/513481