# pass lambda as Windows CALLBACK function failed

Tags: c++11, winapi

```
static std::function<LRESULT(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)> keyProc =
        [](int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)->LRESULT {
        return 1;
    };
    keyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyProc, theApp.m_hInstance, NULL);
```

> Error C2664   'HHOOK SetWindowsHookExW(int,HOOKPROC,HINSTANCE,DWORD)':
>   cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::function' to
>   'HOOKPROC'    MFCTest d:\test\mfctest2\mfctest\keymaphooker.cpp   62

PS: Why did I use such a long expression rather than auto? Because I want to it be static.

I changed it to

```
auto keyProc =
        [this](int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)->LRESULT {
         return 1;//return KeyboardProc(keyHook, keyMap, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    };
```

It doesn't work again.

> error C2664: 'HHOOK SetWindowsHookExW(int,HOOKPROC,HINSTANCE,DWORD)':
>   cannot convert argument 2 from
>   'KeyMapHooker::StartHook::'
>   to 'HOOKPROC'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525977/how-can-i-pass-a-c-lambda-to-a-c-callback-that-expects-a-function-pointer-and

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150220-00/?p=44623

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852101/c-lambda-with-captures-as-a-function-pointer

Comment: Unclear, why you are using a lambda at all? What are you trying to accomplish? Why can't you use just a regular function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stateless lambda (such as the one you are using) can indeed be converted to a pointer to function, and thus can be used as `CALLBACK`. However, `std::function` *cannot* be converted in this manner.

Note that the type of a lambda expression **is not** `std::function`, it's an unnamed class type (the *closure type* of the lambda expression). You can capture the correct type using `auto` (which has no effect on storage duration):

```
static auto keyProc =
        [](int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)->LRESULT {
        return 1;
    };
    keyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyProc, theApp.m_hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: Oh, the new version VS can support static auto. I have tried this previously on the vs2010, it couldn't. Now I use VS2017. I have never tried static auto again. Now, I know, I can just use static auto.

Comment: You can also do `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, [](int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) -> LRESULT { ... }, ...);`

Comment: @JonathanPotter Then the lambda will not be static, of course.

Comment: Wait!!!! I just tried your code can work. But, When I add a capture: [this](/*others don't change*/)... It doesn't work again.

Comment: @马化腾 Of course. As I said (and as the standard says), only *stateless* lambdas (i.e. lambdas which don't capture anything) can be converted to function pointers.

Comment: @Angew, that makes the lambda be less useful :(

Comment: @马化腾 Think about it.  How would `this` get passed to `SetWindowsHookEx`?  A (non-stateless) lambda is more than just a simple C-style function pointer.

Comment: @马化腾 Also, having a static lambda capturing `this` smells like trouble. Is the class a singleton?

Comment: If you want the usefulness of combining capturing lambdas with the ability to pass it as a function pointer you can use libffi's closure system. It creates (small) chunks of binary at run-time. It's not as convenient syntactically but it enables some very useful idioms.