# Casting the std::function to the C function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, std-function

I have a problem with casting:
the `std::function <int32_t (std::string &, uint32_t)>` to the `typedef int32_t (*callback_c_type) (std::string &, uint32_t` (C function pointer).

My **full example**:
https://onlinegdb.com/5KI36oPlQ

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

typedef int32_t (*callback_c_type) (std::string &, uint32_t);
static int counter = 0;

int32_t my_callback (std::string & index, uint32_t var_id)
{
  std::cout << "my_callback => index: '" << index 
  << " var_id: '" << var_id 
  << "'" << " counter = " << counter << std::endl;
  counter++;
  return 42;
}

void execute_c_callback(callback_c_type cb)
{
  std::cout << "execute_c_callback" << std::endl;
  std::string text = "foo";
  cb(text, 777);
}

int main ()
{
  callback_c_type cb = &my_callback;
  execute_c_callback(cb);

  std::function <int32_t (std::string &, uint32_t)> cb_2 = cb;
  // execute_c_callback((callback_c_type)cb_2); 
  // PROBLEM: convert std::function<int32_t(std::string&, uint32_t)> -> callback_c_type
    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of casting to `const char*` and back? It doesn't add anything but problems.

Comment: `register_c_callback` should probably accept `callback_c_type` argument instead of `char const *`. This won't help with passing an `std::function` object though.

Comment: Please be more specific than "I have a problem". And don't post links to code, post the code.

Comment: I think a [mcve] would be helpful. But from what I can see, I don't believe this can be done with casts. You likely need an adapter function/object of some sort.

Comment: @molbdnilo Because the external C library requires it.
I have to use `const char*` to pass the function pointer.
@Fred Larson  https://onlinegdb.com/Sk9GIVTZa

Comment: What library is that? Who made that library? Are you _sure_ that the library casts `const char *` pointer into a function pointer to call that pointer? If the library does that, do not use that library - for sure it's a very bad library. || The presented code is not working, becuase `)>*>(&cb);` -  `&cb` is the address of `cb` pointer, not it's value. Maybe you want to `reinterpret_cast<....>(cb)`. Still, it depends on some assumptions - consider adding at least `static_assert(alignof(const char *) == alignof(std::function<....>)`.

Comment: If it's a C library, you can't use any C++ types and must stick to the appropriate C prototype. `int32_t (std::string &, uint32_t)` can't possibly work. I suspect that you have misunderstood the callback interface.

Comment: From the link it appears you are trying to do `func(text, 123)` where `func` is actually of type `std::function<int32_t(std::string &, uint32_t)> *`.  Please edit your question to provide all relevant code/information as text.

Comment: @KamilCuk You certainly can’t/don’t want to cast `cb` to `char const*`. Instead you’d cast the pointer (as the code currently does), then inside the function cast it back and dereference it. The code is trivial to fix (just make `func` inside the function a reference) but of course that won’t help OP with the actual library.

Comment: I do binding to a library written in rust. I want to pass a c++ callback(std::function) to rust library by `const char*`. Classic C function pointer working correctly.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#callbacks-from-c-code-to-rust-functions
https://cxx.rs/

Comment: @MichałHanusek But (a) why would the type of the Rust callback be `char const*`? And (b) you still can’t pass a `std::function` to the Rust library. It expects a C function pointer, not a pointer to a `std::function` object.

Comment: There is an underlying question that can be answered, but it's hidden behind the issue of using `char const*` for a callback. The Rustonomicon uses `typedef void (*rust_callback)(int32_t);` to register a callback, which is a proper function pointer type. If you change your example to use proper function pointer type, then maybe people are willing to answer the underlying question about `std::function` vs pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`std::function` is a class (template) with a misleading name: It *is not a function*. It is rather a *polymorphic function (object) wrapper*. Let's take that apart: it's a wrapper class for functions and function objects, and it's polymorphic in the sense of *type erasure*.

The main job of `std::function` is to store arbitrary callable objects (function objects) and provide a single interface for them:

```cpp
double myFunc(int);

struct MyStruct {
    double operator()(int);
};

std::function<int(double)> f = myFunc; // can store function pointers
f = MyStruct{}; // or class instances
// ... and many more
```

The type of `f` is the same, while the type of the thing stored inside can differ. This is called *type erasure*.

---

A C callback with signature `int32_t (*) (std::string &, uint32_t)` expects a *function pointer*. In other words, a pointer to a piece of executable code.

You cannot pass a class object as a function pointer, since a class object is not a piece of code but a piece of data, with *related* pieces of code (the member functions).

Thinking about it in terms of state, a *function* is stateless. It's always the same piece of code. A *class object* can be stateful (if it has any members, for example).

A function pointer is a single pointer to executable code, it cannot transfer state directly. Therefore, many C callbacks have an additional parameter to pass state:

```cpp
typedef int32_t (*callback_c_type) (void* state, std::string &, uint32_t);
```

With such a signature, you can pass the function object as a pointer through the callback "bottleneck" and restore it on the other end, but with caveats:

```cpp
typedef int32_t (*callback_c_type) (void*, std::string &, uint32_t);

void execute_c_callback(callback_c_type cb, void* state)
{
  std::cout << "execute_c_callback" << std::endl;
  std::string text = "foo";
  cb(state, text, 777);
}

using plain_cb_signature = int32(std::string&, uint32_t);

int32_t callback_wrapper(void* state, std::string &s, uint32_t i)
{
    auto* f = static_cast<std::function<plain_cb_signature>*>(state);
    (*f)(s, i);
}

int main ()
{
  std::function <int32_t (std::string &, uint32_t)> cb_2 = cb;
  auto* f = &cb;
  execute_c_callback(callback_wrapper, f); 
    
  return 0;
}
```

The trouble here is maintaining the lifetime of `cb`, in other words, keeping the state valid long enough for all invocations of `execute_c_callback`.

Usually one writes `callback_wrapper` as a generic function template. See, for example, [this version by Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20527578/420683).